# How to extract custom tokens in SQL Server NVarChar/VarChar field by using RegEx?

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there any way to extract the matched strings by using Regex in T-SQL(SQL Server 2005)?

For example:

> Welcome [CT Name="UserName" /],
>     We hope that you will enjoy our services and your subscription will be expired on [CT Name="ExpiredDate" /].

I would like to extract the custom tokens in tabular format as follows:

```
[CT Name="UserName" /]
[CT Name="ExpiredDate" /]
```

Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .Net Clr functions.

Here is the [Regular-Expression-Replace](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/27/SQL-2005-Regular-Expression-Replace.aspx) sample, you can get the idea and apply it to your problem.

EDIT:

try this regex to find what you want

```
var s = "Welcome [CT Name=\"UserName\" /], We hope that you will enjoy our services and your subscription will be expired on [CT Name=\"ExpiredDate\" /].";
var pattern = "\\[CT\\s\\w+=\"\\w+\"\\s/\\]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @Jani .. Thanks for your prompt answer .. Actually, I've already found some samples but none of them seems working for me. May be I am bad at writing regex.

Comment: But I tested it with what you copied and it returns 2 matches, Copy the string in your question exactly and run it again

Comment: Copy and paste the edited answer to a new console application and you get it.

Comment: @Jani .. I am sorry to have confused you. It is working perfectly now. I forgot to remove extra "\" when I passed it to CLR StoredProc Test Script ... +1 Thanks a lot ..